# Altering a URL alias without using a module

Tags: 7, path-aliases

Is there a way to alter a URL alias without using a module? Somebody told me to write a record into database table, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal allows to add (and alter) a path alias using the user interface. Generally, there is no reason to alter a database table directly, especially when a Drupal core module allows to do what you are trying to achieve through an administrative page.

If you need to do it from code, then you can use `path_set_alias()` function as pointed out from tim.plunkett. Differently, Drupal user interface is preferable for such tasks.

The query used by `path_set_alias()` to update an existing alias is similar to the following (I simplified the query by removing the reference to the language field):

```
UPDATE {url_alias} SET src = '<alias>', dst = '<destination>' WHERE dst = '<old_destination>'
```

If your Drupal site is using table prefixes (e.g. `dr6_`) then you need to replace `{url_alias}` with `dr6_url_alias`; if your Drupal site is not using table prefixes, then replace `{url_alias}` with `url_alias`.
Replace also `<alias>` in the query I wrote with the path alias, `<destination>` with the path to alias, and `<old_destination>` with the old path (which can also be the same value used for `<destination>`).

If there isn't a path alias, then the query becomes the following one:

```
INSERT INTO {url_alias} (src, dst) VALUES ('<alias>', '<destination>')
```

`<alias>` and `<destination>` have the same meaning I reported before.

Comment: What is the purpose of reposting my exact answer?

Comment: i put this code in preprocess_page function, if (isset($node->path) && $node->type=='story') {
         path_set_alias('node/' . $node->nid, $node->path.'/test', NULL, $language);
       }
but it doesn't work.

Comment: @tim.plunkett: You didn't suggest to do it through the user interface, as far as I can see.

Comment: @enjoylife: I would not suggest to alter a path alias inside `hook_preprocess_page()`. Is there any reason you cannot change the path alias from the user interface? Your question was asking about doing it without using a module, but from your comment I get you are using a module (whenever it is your custom module or a third-party module, it is still a module).

Answer (score 1):

Inserting values directly into the database is a poor choice when there is an API available.
The function you are looking for is [path_set_alias()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--path--path.module/function/path_set_alias/6).

If you absolutely insist on inserting rows directly into the database, the table is {url_alias}.

Comment: i put this code in preprocess_page function, if (isset($node->path) && $node->type=='story') { path_set_alias('node/' . $node->nid, $node->path.'/test', NULL, $language); } but it doesn't work. if i inserting rows directly into the database,how and where to write and put the code in.

Comment: You would only set an alias once, not on every page load. Hence, you would need to write a module.

If you don't want to use a module, then go into your database directly and add another row.

If you want generic paths, use [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto).

Comment: if i want to add the test after the node story content type. how to alter the database?